# python generator return "generator object" and not value

Tags: python, debugging, generator

I wrote a generator but it didn't execute (line number 5 didn't execute in `my_func`, but generated a generator object at line number 17).
In debugging mode, even the debugger didn't execute the first debug point at line 5.

[image]

I am wondering how my code is generating a "generator object" without entering into the corresponding function `my_func`.

My code:

```
import time
import os

def my_func(fileName,data):
    print("generator Started")  # line 5
    with open(fileName,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            data = line.split(",")
            if data in (data[0]):
                yield line
def calling_func():
    start = time.time()
    dirName = "D:\\Datasets"
    filName = "data.txt"
    fileName = os.path.join(dirName,filName)
    keyword1 = 49
    data = my_func(fileName,keyword1)  # line 17
    print(x for x in data)
    print("time taken ----=>",(time.time() - start))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    calling_func()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the **exact purpose** of a generator.

From https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/generator:

> If a function contains at least one `yield` statement (it may contain
>   other `yield` or `return` statements), it becomes a generator function.
>   Both `yield` and `return` will return some value from a function.

Since `my_func` uses `yield` the function is a generator.

> The difference is that, while a `return` statement terminates a function
>   entirely, `yield` statement pauses the function saving all its states
>   and later continues from there on successive calls.

When you called `data = my_func(fileName,keyword1)` you created a generator ("generator object").
Now when you iterate it in `print(x for x in data)`, each iteration will execute `my_func` until `my_func` is exhuasted.

Comment: Dear Maor Rafaeli, Thanks for your response. But when I replace the "yield" with "return" also getting "generator Object".

Comment: @RadhaRani What you are saying is simply not possible (or you have another `yield` in your version of `my_func`). If you run the code in your question and replace the `yield` with `return` (and fix the bug in line 9 `if data in (data[0]):`, the left operand cannot be a list), it simply returns a value and no generator is created.